# GPO to copy a file to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16

Tags: group-policy, copying

I need to copy (MSCAL.OCX) a file to the same directory as MSACCESS.exe for my application to work.

I used this as a tutorial

http://kunaludapi.blogspot.com/2015/08/copy-files-on-all-computers-using-group.html

but for whatever reason, the OCX file is not being copied to the destination.

Comment: Cool story, bro.

Comment: What happens when you try to do this?

Comment: the file doesn't copy. I looked at Event Viewer (a few seconds ago and it says ACCESS DENIED). I thought gpupdate runs as SYSTEM (or an elevated account). The target PC's are Win 10/7

Comment: ...on the local system. But the share (and the folder/file) must be readable by _Everyone_.

Comment: The share is readable by "Authenticated Users"